# Facebook showing accounts on my phone number

Tags: facebook

I created 3 Facebook accounts on one phone number. I removed phone numbers from these 3 accounts. But still Facebook shows those 3 accounts whenever I enter my phone number in "Forgotten password". I don't want any accounts to show up whenever I type my phone number. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have violated [Facebook Community Standard](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards/) by creating multiple accounts:

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/975828035803295?helpref=uf_permalink):

> Facebook is a community where people use their authentic identities. It's against the Facebook Community Standards to maintain more than one personal account.

Next, hope you have followed the [process to remove you mobile number from Facebook account](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/124895950923762?helpref=platform_switcher&ref=platform_switcher).

Now, if it is showing all three account when you are entering phone number, I suspect you have not added email address, because when you add a mobile number to a Facebook account which is already being used by other Facebook account, it would be removed from that account and will be added to new account.

So, if you want it should not show all the account, login (or recover) one by one account and add an email address to every account. If after that if possible delete all account which is not necessary. I don't see any other way.